# Newton-Raphson Method for Non-linear System of 3 variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization, newtons-method

I am trying to solve 3 non-linear system of 3 variables using the Newton-Raphson method in MATLAB. Here are the 3 non-linear equations:

```
c * (alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q))-I *alpha      = 0

s * (lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q))- lambda_b* c * P_C  = 0

q * ( gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q))- (c * k_p * (P_C / P_Q))  = 0
```

I need to find the values of `c`, `s`, and `q` using the Newton-Raphson method.

Here's what I have so far:

```
format long
clear;

%values of parameters
I=1200;
k_f= 6.7*10.^7;
k_d= 6.03*10.^8; 
k_n=2.92*10.^9; 
k_p=4.94*10.^9;
lambda_b= 0.0087;
lambda_r =835; 
gamma =2.74; 
alpha =1.14437*10.^-3;
P_C= 3 * 10.^(11);
P_Q= 2.87 * 10.^(10);

tol = 10.^-4;  %tol is a converge tolerance

%initial guess or values
c=1; 
s=0.015;
q=0.98;
x0= [c;s;q];

iter= 0; %iterations
xnew =[100;100;100];
while norm(xnew -x0) > tol
    iter= iter + 1;
%Defining the functions for c,s and q.
f = c * (alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q))-I *alpha;
g = s * (lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q))- lambda_b* c * P_C; 
h = q * ( gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q))- (c * k_p * (P_C / P_Q));

%Partial derivatives in terms of c,s and q.
dfdc = alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q);
dfds = k_n *c ;
dfdq = - k_p *c;

dgdc = lambda_b * P_C *(s-1);
dgds = lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q);
dgdq = - lambda_r * s;

dhdc = k_p *(P_C / P_Q)*(q-1);
dhds = 0;
dhdq = gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q);

%Jacobian matrix 
J = [dfdc dfds dfdq; dgdc dgds dgdq; dhdc dhds dhdq];    
% Applying the Newton-Raphson method
xnew = x0 - J\[f;g;h];
disp(sprintf('iter=%6.15f,  c=%6.15f,  s=%6.15f, q=%6.15f', iter,xnew)); 
end
```

can someone please check my code, there are some errors so, its not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: not errors, but I think I am not getting accurate values of c,s,q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your guess for `c`, `s`, and `q` (`x0`) between iterations. Try the following:

```
%initial guess or values
c=1; 
s=0.015;
q=0.98; 

xnew =[c;s;q];
xold = zeros(size(xnew));
while norm(xnew - xold) > tol
    iter= iter + 1;
    xold = xnew;

    % update c, s, and q
    c = xold(1);
    s = xold(2);
    q = xold(3);

    %Defining the functions for c,s and q.
    f = c * (alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q))-I *alpha;
    g = s * (lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q))- lambda_b* c * P_C; 
    h = q * ( gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q))- (c * k_p * (P_C / P_Q));

    %Partial derivatives in terms of c,s and q.
    dfdc = alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q);
    dfds = k_n *c ;
    dfdq = - k_p *c;

    dgdc = lambda_b * P_C *(s-1);
    dgds = lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q);
    dgdq = - lambda_r * s;

    dhdc = k_p *(P_C / P_Q)*(q-1);
    dhds = 0;
    dhdq = gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q);

    %Jacobian matrix 
    J = [dfdc dfds dfdq; dgdc dgds dgdq; dhdc dhds dhdq];    
    % Applying the Newton-Raphson method
    xnew = xold - J\[f;g;h];
    disp(sprintf('iter=%6.15f,  c=%6.15f,  s=%6.15f, q=%6.15f', iter,xnew)); 
end
```

I changed `x0` to be `xold` in the above, and made sure that it is updated with each iteration of the loop. Basically you are trying to "walk" your guesses closer to the nominal values using this method. Check out [this website](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der07/der07.html) for a good discussion of the basic concepts involved in this algorithm.

With the changes above, your code ends up converging after six iterations with:

```
iter=1.000000000000000,  c=0.000000000389029,  s=0.015000000287216, q=0.979999999955780
iter=2.000000000000000,  c=0.000000001356998,  s=0.158028331191731, q=0.923765241962920
iter=3.000000000000000,  c=0.000000001181617,  s=0.104156261426515, q=0.952886937302707
iter=4.000000000000000,  c=0.000000001216663,  s=0.085849634576983, q=0.958360887077671
iter=5.000000000000000,  c=0.000000001224388,  s=0.084367460093642, q=0.958463129596494
iter=6.000000000000000,  c=0.000000001224423,  s=0.084367992582976, q=0.958463625488450
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I don't have matlab at home. I will run your code tomorrow. just being curious , what values did you get for c,s, and q? Did you have to go for more that 1 iteration to converge it? As I remember, my code got only 1 iteration when I run it at uni.

Comment: I am only concern about this line: disp(sprintf('iter=%6.15f, c=%6.15f, s=%6.15f, q=%6.15f', iter,xnew)); I want to display xnew as new and accurate values for c,s and q. Is this code giving the correct and update values of c,s,q as xnew? Sorry if my question looks silly.

Comment: Yes, this will display the latest value of `xnew` before it quits.

Comment: Not a problem, happy I could help.

Comment: Really appreciate your help  sir :)